# Unknown React Declaration For Global

Tags: reactjs

In react i have seen this declaration but i am not able to find where these are defined And when i console log them i.e **GlobalCartStore** they contains objects.
Do you know what is the name for this declarations? Where can i find in the project ?
How can I create or use a global variable in a function?

```
/*global AccountStore:true, GlobalCartStore:tru,WishlistStore:true, ImgServices:true*/
'use strict';
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make it a bit clear bro, i can just say, If you load React from a  tag, these top-level APIs are available on the ReactDOM global. If you use ES6 with npm, you can write import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'. If you use ES5 with npm, you can write var ReactDOM = require('react-dom'). via from React docs, bro